# Round numbers in a set of limits

Tags: computer-science

I'm trying to create a mathematical operation that help me to resolve this scenario.

I have a list of "limits" as show below:

> 0---4---8---12... (n + 4)

Suppose that we have a software that "read" a number, an it determines what is the previous "step limit". For example:

```
Given | Previous limit step
3     | 1 (the limit would be 0)
4     | 2 (the limit would be 4)
7     | 2 (the limit would be 4)
9     | 3 (the limit would be 8)
```

What I need to do is trying to get the previous limit in question, as show below:

```
Given | Previous limit
3     | 0
4     | 4
7     | 4
9     | 8
```

I have two days dealing with a formula to get it, but no good results.

Comment: I feel so stupid.. viewing the results as table I think that the formula is `limit = 4(n-1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x - (x \text{ mod } 4)$ should be what you are looking for. $\text{a mod b}$ returns the *remainder* of $a$ divided by $b$, i.e. what remains of $a$ if you subtract $b$ is many times as possible without making the result negative. In a of programming languages, operator "%" means $\text{mod}$, so you'd write `x - (x % 4)` to compute your "previous limit".

Comment: You are correct